# What "meritless patent litigation" has Facebook been victim too that the BSD + Patents license would prevent?

Tags: intellectual-property, patents

Facebook claims [here,](https://code.facebook.com/posts/112130496157735/explaining-react-s-license)

> The patent grant says that if you're going to use the software we've released under it, you lose the patent license from us if you sue us for patent infringement. **We believe that if this license were widely adopted, it could actually reduce meritless litigation** for all adopters, and we want to work with others to explore this possibility.

Does Facebook have any reason to believe that? Have they ever been a defendant in a patent suit by a company that used products that they released under the BSD license? It seems like they're trying to turn their software into a legal weapon.

I sense drama here, and I just wanted to know more.

Answer (score -1):

Earlier in the same paragraph they say "... we've become a larger target for meritless patent litigation." So, yes.

Comment: Yes, I can read that. so just take their word for it? What inspired this, and what would it have prevented?